# Matplotlib pie chart with explode not round

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart, explode, donut-chart

Edit: I cannot share actual data, but here is an example dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'education_grouped': ['None', 'Primary', 'Secondary', 
'Post-secondary', 'Bachelor', 'Master', 'Doctoral', 'None', 'Primary', 
'Secondary', 'Post-secondary', 'Bachelor', 'Master', 'Doctoral', 'None', 
'Primary', 'Secondary', 'Post-secondary', 'Bachelor', 'Master', 'Doctoral']})
```

I am making a donut pie chart using the following code

```
sizes = df['education_grouped'].value_counts().sort_index() / df['education_grouped'].value_counts().sum() * 100
educ_order2 = ['None', 'Primary', 'Secondary', 'Post-secondary', 'Bachelor', 'Master', 'Doctoral'] 

cmap = plt.get_cmap("Set2")
colors = cmap(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))
explode = (0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes,
        labels=educ_order2,
        startangle=90,
        explode=explode,
        colors=colors,
        counterclock=False,
        shadow=False,
        wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'white'},
        textprops={'fontsize': 7},
        pctdistance=0.8,
        autopct='%1.1f%%')

centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.70,fc='white')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)

ax1.axis('equal')
plt.title('Educational attainment', fontsize=16, pad=20)
plt.tight_layout()
```

However, I am bothered by the fact that it does not appear as a circle anymore. See below it seems that some pieces move out further than others. This seems strange to me as I exploded all slices by the same amount. Does anybody have a hint at what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the DataFrame that is the input?

Comment: Added an example dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably best to put the explode parameter off. Putting it at zero removes the inequalities. By contrast, you may want to adapt `radius`

```
sizes = df['education_grouped'].value_counts().sort_index() /    df['education_grouped'].value_counts().sum() * 100
educ_order2 = ['None', 'Primary', 'Secondary', 'Post-secondary', 'Bachelor', 'Master', 'Doctoral'] 

cmap = plt.get_cmap("Set2")
colors = cmap(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,12))
ax1.pie(sizes,
    labels=educ_order2,
    radius=1,
    explode=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    startangle=90,
    colors=colors,
    counterclock=False,
    shadow=False,
    wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'white', 'linewidth': 4},
    textprops={'fontsize': 7},
    pctdistance=0.85,
    autopct='%1.1f%%')

centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.70,fc='white')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)

ax1.axis('equal')
plt.title('Educational attainment', fontsize=16, pad=20)
plt.tight_layout()
```

If you put one of them a bit higher, for ex. `explode=[0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, it gives a nice special effect to one of the pies. The parameter was probably designed to highlight one or a few of the fractions.